# After fresh Debian install bootable USB drives freeze BIOS

Tags: linux, usb, debian, hardware-failure, uefi

- **Laptop**: Acer aspire A515-56
- **Debian Release**: 12.4.0
- **Mint releas**e: 21.2
- **System BIOS versio**n: v1.12
- **Flashing method**: Balena etcher on kali workstation
  PS. It says BIOS version, but UEFI boot is the only option

I installed Linux Mint on my laptop and decided to switch to Debian after Linux Mint had an issue.

After I installed Debian I restarted and it brought me to the Grub loader instead of the desktop. Even though I chose to erase the disk for a complete fresh install, Mint was still there as a boot option.

I decided I would try another fresh install and now I can't access my UEFI with a bootable USB plugged in. Everything boots fine if a normal USB is plugged in, but a bootable USB locks up the screen on the Acer logo and I have to use a pin to click the shutoff button on the bottom of the laptop.

Note this only happens when trying to access the UEFI. I don't know if this is a UEFI issue or a Linux issue or even an hardware issue, but it only started after installing Debian. If any more information is needed feel free to ask and I'll provide it.

Comment: *I figured out that even though I chose to erase the disk for a complete fresh install, Mint was still there* No, you figured out wrong. Please accept the edit then [edit] again and provide specifics: Hardware specifications (brand/model, etc.), which Debian release/version you tried to install, how did you you make the installation media, etc. PS - If your computer is newer than 2012 it has UEFI, not BIOS.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I hope i've made all the correct changes along with your edit.

Comment: Acer aspire A515-56 is very new so it requires newer OS/drivers/software. Both choices are fine but with Debian you need to select a few options to enable all the drivers and firmware to be installed. Debian is good(-ish) for newbies but certainly far from being easy, especially with new hardware and/or Nvidia graphics (not applicable). Mint is much easier and, personal opinion, Ubuntu even better because it has much more and better support (Mint is an unofficial derivative). Etcher is fine for any, that isn't the problem, but the actual USB stick you're using might be.

Comment: PS - I said *accept the edit then edit again*. Edits are rewarded with +2 points.

Comment: Anyway, if your intention was to have Mint there's no reason to start distro hooping just becasue *Linux Mint had an issue*. You could've and should've asked about THAT issue.

Comment: I'm not so sure if the usb is the issue, as i've tried two usbs and the issue only persists when the usb is flashed with an iso. The one usb is fresh out the box and had nothing on it prior to flashing, and didnt cause any issues when plugged in during boot, only after fashing it was there an issue. As for newer drivers would it be recommended that I try to update my UEFI? The whole reason I wanted to use Debian is because the "most stable" according to reddit, but i'll probably just stick to ubuntu.

Comment: The "most stable" is mostly BS as Reddit itself. Acer laptops do behave in weird ways after an OS is installed, particularly Linux. But if you need to change settings in UEFI then access them without additional devices. Recommended to disable any Legacy/CSM mode and Fast Boot. Then connect the installer and use the boot override / one-time boot menu to select it and proceed with a new installation. Again, Ubuntu is much more user friendly but you do you. Updating UEFI may or may not be necessary (lately it has been recommended indeed).

Comment: I will defiinitely try this and let you know how it works. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Thank you this method worked for me. I was able to switch to ubuntu and haven't had any issues with my laptop so far. I really appreciate the help. Would you be able to write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary note: The following goes on tangents and doesn't directly answer the question as it is, rather to what has been discussed in comments.**

An Acer Aspire A515-56 is new enough to require a very current distro for optimal hardware support.

The author has been trying different distros, namely **Linux Mint 21.2** and **Debian 12.4**. As posted in comments, both are good choices because both are the latest stable releases at the time of this writing. However, as discussed, Ubuntu is likely the best choice here - personal opinion - given it has a much larger and arguably better support base.

Regarding the laptop itself it was recommended to change a few settings in UEFI, namely disabling Legacy/CSM mode and Fast Boot.

Once set accordingly the author booted the Ubuntu installation/live media by selecting it in the Boot Override / One-time Boot menu and proceeded with the standard installation.

The author reported no issues so far.